# Tensorflow "Ran out of memory trying to allocate 4B"

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I've got a small network running in TensorFlow on a laptop without GPU support. I'm now trying to run it on a Linux box with a GPU, where I *believe* I've installed everything properly. (Certainly TensorFlow's "Hello, world!" example runs.)

When I try to run my program, though, I get an error that begins with this mysterious line:

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:275] Ran out of memory trying to allocate 4B.  See logs for memory state.
```

Really? 4 bytes? I don't think my GPU is *that* small.

I have two theories, but no real clue as to how to proceed:

1. Some installation detail or command-line option is not set up properly, so that my program is allocating 0 memory for the GPU.
2. I've made some mistake in my program that happens to not cause a problem when running without a GPU but crashes when I do have a GPU.

Here's a longer version of the output:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
inputs (1619, 691200)
<OUTPUT SPECIFIC TO MY PROGRAM APPEARS HERE>
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:910] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 650
major: 3 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.0585
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 973.69MiB
Free memory: 796.44MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 650, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (256):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (512):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (1024):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (2048):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (4096):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (8192):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (16384):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (32768):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (65536):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (131072):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (262144):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (524288):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (1048576):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (2097152):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (4194304):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (8388608):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (16777216):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (33554432):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (67108864):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (134217728):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (268435456):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:660] Bin for 256B was 256B, Chunk State: 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x500b80000 of size 1280
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x500b80500 of size 256
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x500b80600 of size 512
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x500b80800 of size 2764800
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x500e23800 of size 256
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x500e23900 of size 256
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x500e23a00 of size 276480000
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:678] Chunk at 0x5115cfa00 of size 346162688
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:693]      Summary of in-use Chunks by size: 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 3 Chunks of size 256 totalling 768B
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 1 Chunks of size 512 totalling 512B
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 1 Chunks of size 1280 totalling 1.2KiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 1 Chunks of size 2764800 totalling 2.64MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 1 Chunks of size 276480000 totalling 263.67MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:696] 1 Chunks of size 346162688 totalling 330.13MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:700] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 596.44MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:702] Stats: 
Limit:                   625410048
InUse:                   625410048
MaxInUse:                625410048
NumAllocs:                       8
MaxAllocSize:            346162688

W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:274] *****************************************************************************************xxxxxxxxxxx
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:275] Ran out of memory trying to allocate 4B.  See logs for memory state.
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:983] Internal: Dst tensor is not initialized.
E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:594] Executor failed to create kernel. Internal: Dst tensor is not initialized.
     [[Node: random_uniform/sub/_1__cf__1 = Const[dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor<type: float shape: [] values: 2>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/drake/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1022, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/drake/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1004, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/home/drake/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 89, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/home/drake/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Dst tensor is not initialized.
     [[Node: random_uniform/sub/_1__cf__1 = Const[dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor<type: float shape: [] values: 2>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tinyAE.py", line 55, in <module>
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  File "/home/drake/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/drake/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/drake/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/drake/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Dst tensor is not initialized.
     [[Node: random_uniform/sub/_1__cf__1 = Const[dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor<type: float shape: [] values: 2>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```